# Emulator not start in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I try repeatedly to start AVD in different configuration but I obtain error "/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property". I use armV7 for Android Lollipop in this cases. In this case seems that some property is not defined correctly in build.conf file. If the deduction is correctly, for an emulator where I can found this file to define this property?

Comment: What is your android studio version?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying create avd for lollipop device are also some other one.  If same error is persisting for another devices then try to use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter#!/) as alternative to avd.
It is much better and faster than the emulator provided by android.

Comment: The question is about how to set some properties not about some AVD alternative. However, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Have you found any solution to your problem ?